# How to delete whole key data in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I making an app using Firebase. Structure of my data storage is-

[image]

I am calling subject and description in another activity to show them. I added a button in that activity which delete that particular key(-L6g7ttOxr... highlighted portion) data shown in Image above. I successfully got that key in second activity for particular list item to give database reference.

```
public void deleteCurrentMemo(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            DisplayMemo.this);
    alert.setTitle("Delete Memo");
    alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete current Memo?");
    Toast.makeText(this,key,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mMemoDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("memos").child(key);
            mMemoDatabaseReference.removeValue();
            finish();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

Above code is in second activity called on delete Button. Now how can I delete complete key data?

Comment: You've gotten quite some downvotes. Most likely that is because you shared links to screenshots of text. I made the images visible, but please replace them with the actual code and JSON as text. You can get the JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Having the actual text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and code and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the key of the memo to the second activity.

Typically this is quite easy, since you already get the key when you read the data from Firebase. Just pass is along with the subject and subscription to the second activity, and then into `deleteCurrentMemo`.

Comment: This code written in question is not deleting key data. But when I remove    child(key)   then it is deleting whole database. I want to delete specific key data. What I am missing here?

Comment: Calling `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("memos").removeValue()` will remove all memos. Calling `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("memos").child(key).removeValue()` will (at most) only remove the specific memo identified by `key`.  If that's not happening for you, step through the code in a debugger and check if each variable has the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

By this way i have successfully delete child node.

N:B You must need key of your node that you want to delete.

```
    database.getReference().child("Groups").child(groupItem.getGroupkey()).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        new CustomMessage(GroupDetailsActivity.this, "Successfully deleted");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Customlog.showlogD("ERROR_MSG",e.getMessage());
                    }
                })

;
```